# How to setup unit testing in Qt - Visual Studio 2013 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, unit-testing

I want to be able to use the Visual Studio unit testing framework to test Qt libraries created with the QT Visual Studio add-in. Currently there is no out-of-the-box way to create a native C++ Unit Test with Qt Meta Object Compiler support. The need for this is if you want to unit-test classes that uses the Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: Any reason for not using the testing framework of Qt?

Comment: Just integration with the Test Explorer of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this worked very well for me:

I created a "Qt Library" project using the template provided with the Qt Visual Studio add-in.

Then I did the following modifications on the properties of the project:

- Added $(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include to the "Additional Include Directories"
- Added $(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib to the "Additional Library Directories".
- Added my tests like this in a .cpp file:

  ```
  #include "CppUnitTest.h"
  using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
  namespace MyUnitTests
  {       
      TEST_CLASS(MyTestClass)
      {
      public:

          TEST_METHOD(MyTestFunction)
          {
              // TODO: Your test code here

          }

      };
  }
  ```

Comment: There are some extra steps to help people get started. For example: #include <CppUnitTestLogger.h>, add a reference to the project to test, and add dependencies to the .obj files, and add the project being tested include and lib folders to the additional directories.